Hibernate: How can I assign a default value to the enum in the embedded class
@Embeddable
public class BaseEntity{
    @Basic
    @Column(columnDefinition = "varchar(50) default 'ACTIVE'")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Status status = Status.ACTIVE;
    @CreationTimestamp
    private Date createdAt;
    @UpdateTimestamp
    private Date updatedAt;
}

I am using this BaseEntity class in other Entity classes. I have learned how to give values for createdAt and updatedAt fields. but I could not find how to give Status.ACTIVE value to status field by default. Can I do this with hibernate?

BaseEntity Class:
@Embeddable
public class BaseEntity {
    public BaseEntity() {
        this.status = BaseStatus.ACTIVE;
    }
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private BaseStatus status;
    @CreationTimestamp
    private Date createdAt;
    @UpdateTimestamp
    private Date updatedAt;
}

Entity Class:
@Builder
@Entity
public class Entity{
    @Builder.Default
    private BaseEntity baseEntity = new BaseEntity();
}

That did the job for me.

Default values can be set in your DB/DDL.
